# Proving $\frac{\cot\theta-\csc\theta+1}{\cot\theta+\csc\theta-1}=\csc\theta-\cot\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that 
>   $$\frac{\cot\theta - \csc\theta + 1}{\cot\theta+\csc\theta-1}= \csc\theta-\cot\theta$$

Comment: Try to improve your text.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have replaced 1 by csc2(theta) - cot2(theta).

Comment: Write $1=\csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta$ in the numerator

Comment: Hint: To write math, surround what you want to be math with dollar signs '$', put a slash '\' before the math words, and use '^' for exponents.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta - \cot^2\theta = 1 \implies (\operatorname{cosec}\theta+\cot\theta)(\operatorname{cosec}\theta-\cot\theta) = 1$$

$$\operatorname{cosec}\theta+\cot\theta -1= \frac{1}{\operatorname{cosec}\theta-\cot\theta}-1 = \frac{1-(\operatorname{cosec}\theta-\cot\theta)}{\operatorname{cosec}\theta-\cot\theta} = \frac{\cot\theta-\operatorname{cosec}\theta+1}{\operatorname{cosec}\theta-\cot\theta} $$

$$\frac{\cot\theta +\operatorname{cosec}\theta-1}{\cot\theta-\operatorname{cosec}\theta+1}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{cosec}\theta-\cot\theta}$$

> $$\frac{\cot\theta-\operatorname{cosec}\theta+1}{\cot\theta+\operatorname{cosec}\theta -1} = \operatorname{cosec}\theta-\cot\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cot\theta-\csc\theta+1$$
$$=\cot\theta-\csc\theta+(\csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta)$$

$$=(\cot\theta-\csc\theta)(1-\cot\theta-\csc\theta)$$

$$=-(\cot\theta-\csc\theta)(\cot\theta+\csc\theta-1)$$

Comment: @AayushAggarwal, No, We have $$b-a+a^2-b^2=b-a-(a^2-b^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Write $\theta=2y$

$$\cot2y-\csc2y=-\dfrac{1-\cos2y}{\sin2y}=-\tan y$$

$$\cot2y+\csc2y=-\dfrac1{\cot2y-\csc2y}=\cot y$$